# Accessing Nested Objects in JSON (Key Pairs/MYSQL Array)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, nested

I have a mysql query create this output for my json data.  I have not been able to figure out how to access the properties within this output however.

I have tried using data.objA which returns undefined and objA][0] and am at a loss.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

JSON

```
({"objA":"yes","objB":[{"username":"ah2122","client_password":"288c0e42ab41faef3d1015e6fc299644","client_id":"36"}]})
```

PHP

```
<?php
include 'init.php';

//get the posted values
$user_name=htmlspecialchars($_POST['client_username'],ENT_QUOTES);
$pass=md5($_POST['client_password']); 


//now validating the username and password
$sql="SELECT username, client_password, client_id FROM clients WHERE username='".$user_name."'";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {   
             $rows[] = array(
            "username" => $row['username'],
            "client_password" => $row['client_password'],
            "client_id" => $row['client_id']);
        }

        //if username exists
        if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
        {
            //compare the password
            if(strcmp($rows[0]['client_password'],$pass)==0)
            {
                $SUCCESS="yes";
             }
             else
            $SUCCESS="no";
            }
            else
              $SUCCESS="no";  //Invalid Login


$rows2 = array( 'objA' => $SUCCESS, 'objB' => $rows );

$json = json_encode($rows2);

$callback = $_GET['callback'];
echo $callback.'('. $json . ')';    

    ?>
```

SCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#client_login_form").submit(function()
    {
        //remove all the class add the messagebox classes and start fading
        $("#msgbox").removeClass().addClass('messagebox').text('Validating....').fadeIn(1000);
        //check the username exists or not from ajax
        var cu = $("#client_username").val();
        var cp = $("#client_password").val();

        $.post("http://www.website.com/splash/cajax_login.php",{ client_username:cu,client_password:cp,rand:Math.random() } ,function(data)
        {            
          if(data.objA=='yes') //if correct login detail
          {
            $("#msgbox").fadeTo(200,0.1,function()  //start fading the messagebox
            { 
              //add message and change the class of the box and start fading
              $(this).html('Logging in.....').addClass('messageboxok').fadeTo(900,1,
              function()
              { 
                window.localStorage["cusername"] = cu;
                window.localStorage["cpassword"] = cp;  

                //redirect to secure page
                document.location="#client_home";
              });

            });
          }
          else 
          {
            $("#msgbox").fadeTo(200,0.1,function() //start fading the messagebox
            { 
              //add message and change the class of the box and start fading
              $(this).html('Login Failed').addClass('messageboxerror').fadeTo(900,1);
            });     
          }

        });
        return false; //not to post the  form physically
    });
    //now call the ajax also focus move from 
    $("#client_password").blur(function()
    {
        $("#client_login_form").trigger('client_submit');
    });
```

Comment: Your JSON is not JSON ... you'll have to remove the parentheses at the beginning and at the end. Wait ... it seems to be JSONP for which you forgot to hand over the CALLBACK parameter. You should add an if condition to check whether or not there is a CALLBACK parameter. In case there is none, you should remove also the parentheses

Comment: Is www.website.com (or rather the domain that you removed here) on the same domain, sub-domain, protocol and port as the current page or do you try to retrieve JSON(P) from an external server?

Comment: The website is on the same domain, however the end product will be a mobile app using cross domain requests.

Comment: In that case you must not omit the callback parameter and you'll have to use a $.get instead of a $.post, because PHP expects the callback parameter to be sent using the GET method

Comment: Thank you, i ommited the ( and ) at the beginning and end and changed the callback to $.get and am able to get the the whole reponse when I alert(data) but am still left undefined when I try something like alert(data.objA)...thank you for the help, json is still very new to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably the one giving you data.objA undefined

```
echo $callback.'('. $json . ')';
```

Change to

```
   echo $json;
```

This should send back just the json object instead of prepending it with $callback.

Comment: Can you check the `typeof(data)` in the console? It is very likely a string. You would want to convert it into an object via `JSON.parse(data)`

Comment: Yes, that did it, everything is successfully working now, thanks everyone for their help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this code

```
$callback = $_GET['callback'];
echo $callback.'('. $json . ')';
```

to

```
if(isset($_GET['callback'])) {
    echo $_GET['callback'].'('. $json . ')';
} else {
    echo $json;
}
```